# Python website login presents same login form upon clicking login

Tags: python, scrape

I'm at a total loss here. I'm using python to open Edge, enter a user name and password, and then click Log In. I'm not getting any errors.

However, upon clicking login, the login form loads a second time. Now the page displays as an empty login form on top and then the login form I just entered at the bottom.

Basically, hitting Login causes the login form to just load a second time on top of the already completed login form. Below is my code. Any ideas?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import login_details
import time

username = login_details.username
password = login_details.password

driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get("name_of_website")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtUserId").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtPassword").send_keys(password)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"btnLogIn\"]").click()
```

Comment: Include the website so people can test it out for themselves.

Comment: https://infocenter.humana-military.com/provider/service/Account/LogIn

Comment: Instead of using webdrive, you should just use requests to log in by sending a post request to `https://infocenter.humana-military.com/provider/service/Account/LogIn` along with the data 
userId: asdf
password: asdf
__RequestVerificationToken: 65vfvBhzEwxnAKviuY4zdwQYITKpETT-KqYvpysHFk-c04QZ9tFuc5kKyG3tAqo3mjnrvl0Oa9O2uopcb4Xt9zcTUfI1

Comment: The website is not loading, because you didn't entered correct credentials (see my [screenshot](https://snipboard.io/Dgz0ie.jpg) in devtools). If you are trying to hack login, you should use requests to login rather than webdriver as walker suggested.